# What word to use? Anything or everything?

Tags: word-choice

I am creating advertisement for a software company that supports many workflows for various project management methodologies.

[olo] is a name of company. They support scrum, kanban, etc. Ad will show each line of text (e.g. `[olo]scrum`), then switch to next one and the last one should be `olo[anything]`( or `olo[everything]`?)

Meaning of last line should be that it supports any type of software development methodology.

[olo]scrum

[olo]kanban

[olo]agile

[olo]lean

**[olo]anything**

Comment: Anything. If a client is using one SDLC they're not going to need another, and "everything" means all things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, **[olo]anything** is perfect indeed.

As you mentioned **supports any type of software development methodology**.